# ruby on rails extending module in class instance

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, module

using ruby 2.2, rails 4.1

I have a search result class that I would like to use to format the correct results depending on the type of search, ie full text, keyword, etc. Currently I have separate modules for the different search types in the result class, each one knows how to format it's own results. What I would like to do is pass the raw results and the type in to the search result initialize method and within the method, extend the correct module dynamically. then the class that instantiated the search result class (resultbuilder in this case) calls a method defined in the module to format the results. This would need to be called as an instance method, with the same method defined in each module so the resultbuilder just calls one method regardless of search type.

something like this:

```
Class SR
   def initialize(data, type)
      @data = data
      extend type.constantize
   end

   module FullText
      def call
         <format results>
      end
   end
end
```

I can get the extend to work, tho I think I'm missing something as the call method is not available on the SR class instance.

Is there some other way to set up the modules? Do they have to be put into their own files? I prefer not to set up modules that I can dynamically use with generic call and results methods thereby keeping the details out of the resultbuilder.